# Magento Order Email Notification not sent to customer and to admin

Tags: email, sales-order

Am facing problem on order email notification not sent to customer.

I don't know why, but when i search some articles it maybe cause of cron jobs not working.

Here's my error log:

exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail(Array
(
)
)' in /home/ohmyprimus/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
Stack trace:

Comment: `Array ( )` looks like an empty array to me, thus it has no one to send mails to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is that `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::queueNewOrderEmail` doesn't exist prior to version 1.9.1

If you have a version of Magento prior to this, I think the function you're looking for is:

```
sendNewOrderEmail
```

When you view the stack trace, (which exists below the 'Stack Trace:') line in your error log, it will show you the exact file and function that calls this erroneous function.

If you have upgraded, open app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php and look for the queueNewOrderEmail function. If it's not there, then it's possible that you don't have the latest file.